# What is the component responsible for writing the JSESSIONID in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a doubt about Spring Security, when does Spring security write the JsessionId?, what class or method?

Comment: No component, it is the responsibility of your servlet container.

Comment: I have a case where I don't have JsessionId (WS),  how can I create it?.

Comment: By creating a `HttpSession`.

Comment: thank you, I know, but my problem was different because sometimes I had jsession and sometimes no, and I didn't know the cause. The cause of all this is that I have a custom class in Spring Security and I do getSession. And as yet I don't know where is that part of code, and I thought that Spring security do something with the jsession. I will continue investigating. Thank you